# Modal - verticals, and horizontal scrolls

Tags: scrolling, modal

I have a modal in which I have to include 13 columns in a 12-grid column. That would involve a vertical scroll, and a horizontal one. Should i go with pagination so I can do with one of the scrolls?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use a modal to display so much information, that does not make any sense.  If you have a lot of information you need to display the user you might create a seperate page/tab to display it.